# php while loop submit button

Tags: php, button, sql-delete

```
<?php
    $sel22 = mysql_query("SELECT id1nev, id2nev, id2, accept FROM barat WHERE id1= '$kariidje' AND accept = '1' ") or die("CANNOT FETCH DATA FOR ADMIN " . mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sel22) > 0) {
        $i=0;
        while ($data22 = mysql_fetch_array($sel22)) {
            $i++;
          ?><tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        include 'elemek/connection.php'; 
                        $idkitfogadel = $data22['id2'];
                        if(isset($_POST["submitelutasit"])){
                            $updatebaratt1 = "DELETE FROM barat WHERE id1 = $kariidje and id2 = $idkitfogadel";
                            mysql_query($updatebaratt1);
                        //header("Location: friends.php");  
                        }

                    ?>

                    <form id="form<?php echo $i; ?>" method="POST" action="#">
                        <Button type="SUBMIT" name="submitelutasit" id="submitelutasit<?php echo $i;?>" value="!"/></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a>Something</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
<?php
}
```

This is my code in my page. The problem is if I press the button in any line its delete all my data and not only what i want. Each line each button when I press a button its delete that line where is it. This is what i want. I cant solve this problem (sad).

Thank you

Comment: your code makes me sad as well

Comment: Why are you creating so many forms? Put the table in the form, each row add a checkbox input, that has a value="idofdbrow" and just use 1 submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just assume that you are just playing around, and that's not even near to the production code.

Add input field to your form with `id2` so you can use it later.

```
<form id="form<?php echo $i; ?>" method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="id2" value="<?php echo $data22['id2'] ?>">
    <Button type="SUBMIT" name="submitelutasit" id="submitelutasit<?php echo $i;?>" value="!"/></button>
</form>
```

And use it like this:

```
$idkitfogadel = $_POST['id2'];
```

Inside your `if(isset($_POST["submitelutasit"]))` statement.

I'm sure that little kitty died somewhere right now :(